# Why It shows Undefined when I try Access object in array in Next js

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js

I'm trying to display sub Products of the main product so what I have tried is to get the product code from the URL and try to fetch sub-products that match the main product code

```
 List of Products and Sub products
const data ={
 product:[
   {
   title:'Product1',
   slug:'001',
   category:'shirt',
   image:'./../../public/image1.jpg',
   },
   {
   title:'Product2',
   slug:'002',
   category:'shirt',
   image:'./../../public/image2.jpg',
   },
],
subProduct:[
   {
   title:'subProduct1',
   slug:'001',   
   image:'./../../public/image01.jpg',
   price:70
   },
   {
   title:'subProduct2',
   slug:'001',   
   image:'./../../public/image02.jpg',
   price:200
   },
   {
   title:'subProduct3',
   slug:'002',   
   image:'./../../public/image03.jpg',
   price:170
   },
   {
   title:'subProduct4',
   slug:'002',   
   image:'./../../public/image04.jpg',
   price:150
   },

],

}
```

```
  const  slug  = '001';  
  const product = data.product.find(x => x.slug === slug);
  const subProducts =  data.subProduct.filter(function(x) {
  return x.slug == slug;});
  
  
  console.log(subProducts.title)[enter image description here][1]
```

the issue is it shows Undefined when I try implement like `{subProducts.title}`

but when I `console.log(subProducts)` I get Array of subProducts that match with the slug of the Main Product

Comment: based on your example data you have an extra `s` in your code: `data.subProducts` vs `data.subProduct`

Comment: @pilchard Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subProducts` is an array of objects. You're trying to get to `title` attribute of each item in that array but what you are actually doing with `subProducts.title` is that you're trying to reference a `title` property on an array, which yields `undefined`, because the array has no such attribute. The array contains objects as individual items and those are the ones that have the `title` attribute.

So in react (which is part of next.js) when you need to render an array, try something like this:

```
const Component(props) => {
  const subproducts = [{title: 'Foo'}, {title: 'Baz'}]

  return (
    <div>
     {
      subproducts.map((subproduct) => (
        <div key={subproduct.title}>{subproduct.title}</div>
      ))
     }
    </div>
}
```

The `key` tag is required by react. [More on this here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)